# Cardinality of the quotient of two ideals class monoids

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

We fix a number field $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ of degree $4$ that is a CM-field. For an order $O$, if $I(O)$ is the monoid of fractional ideals of $O$ and $P(O)$ is the subgroup of principal fractional ideals, we define the Ideal Class Monoid $ICM(O)$ as the quotient $I(O)/P(O)$.

Given two orders $O\subset O'$, I define the ratio 
$r(O,O')=\frac{\#ICM(O')}{\#ICM(O)}$

Set $R=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha,\bar{\alpha}]$, where $\bar{\alpha}$ is the complex conjugate of $\alpha$, and $R'=R[S(\alpha)/p]$, where $S$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients and $p$ a prime number.

I am interested about the value of $r(R,R')$, or if we have some inequality as for example $r(R,R')\leq 1/p$. Do you have some ideas?

Obs: there is a bijection between $ICM(\mathbb{Z}[\alpha])$ and the conjugacy classes of matrices $M_4(\mathbb{Z})$ with characteristic polynomial the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ [(theorem 3)](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/matrixconj.pdf), but I dont know how that can be useful. It will be interesting to have a bijection with $ICM(\mathbb{Z}[\alpha,\bar{\alpha}])$.

Thanks in advance.